# Linkage Error LNK1104 in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-2010

Today I fired up Visual Studio 2010 (Visual C++) and started working on a project. The solution contains two projects. One is a static library I am writing, the other is a test application containing unit tests for the library.

Without changing anything from yesterday, the executable no longer links:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mylib.lib'
```

The static library compiles and links fine. I have not changed the project settings in around a week, and it was linking just fine yesterday.

If I go into the executable project's settings and add a library directory for `$(SolutionDir)\debug`, I instead get the following link error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
```

I am not sure what the problem is. I have tried cleaning, rebuilding, and even rebooting my machine. Google turned up some bugs in ancient Visual C++ versions (but I'm using 2010), as well as the possibility that the program is already running. However, it is not running, and a reboot confirms this.

What would cause the linker not to find core libraries such as kernel32.lib, or for that matter, the output directory for my solution?

This is old-fashioned C++, a cross-platform library, not that managed stuff Microsoft added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to check "Inherit from parent or project defaults" in the "Library Directories" dialog. Once I did that, the linker could find all the necessary libraries. I still had to include `$(SolutionDir)\debug` though.

Answer (score 3):

Include the microsoft SDK directory in project->properties->linker->general->additional library directories.

on my computer it is

D:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by **disabling "Enable .NET Framework source stepping"** (see: "Menu bar / Tools / Options / Debugging / General / Enable .NET Framework source stepping"). Apparently [this is a bug in Visual Studio](https://connectppe.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/551819/vs2010-locks-static-library-after-debug-session).